# CRC16 for Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc, modbus, crc16

I've been doing a script with python 3 to calculate CRC16 for MODBUS application. I did the same script with python 2.7 years ago and it's working. However whenever I'm importing and running the library and script to Python3, I've having an error

```
File "/home/root/python/CRC16.py", line 14, in calc
    crc_lo=crc_val_low ^ crc_hi
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'
```

Here is the function that I made

```
def calc(data):
        crc_table=[0x0000,0xC0C1,0xC181,0x0140,0xC301,0x03C0,0x0280,0xC241,0xC601,0x06C0,0x0780,0xC741,0x0500,0xC5C1,0xC481,0x0440,0xCC01,0x0CC0,0x0D80,0xCD41,0x0F00,0xCFC1,0xCE81,0x0E40,0x0A00,0xCAC1,0xCB81,0x0B40,0xC901,0x09C0,0x0880,0xC841,0xD801,0x18C0,0x1980,0xD941,0x1B00,0xDBC1,0xDA81,0x1A40,0x1E00,0xDEC1,0xDF81,0x1F40,0xDD01,0x1DC0,0x1C80,0xDC41,0x1400,0xD4C1,0xD581,0x1540,0xD701,0x17C0,0x1680,0xD641,0xD201,0x12C0,0x1380,0xD341,0x1100,0xD1C1,0xD081,0x1040,0xF001,0x30C0,0x3180,0xF141,0x3300,0xF3C1,0xF281,0x3240,0x3600,0xF6C1,0xF781,0x3740,0xF501,0x35C0,0x3480,0xF441,0x3C00,0xFCC1,0xFD81,0x3D40,0xFF01,0x3FC0,0x3E80,0xFE41,0xFA01,0x3AC0,0x3B80,0xFB41,0x3900,0xF9C1,0xF881,0x3840,0x2800,0xE8C1,0xE981,0x2940,0xEB01,0x2BC0,0x2A80,0xEA41,0xEE01,0x2EC0,0x2F80,0xEF41,0x2D00,0xEDC1,0xEC81,0x2C40,0xE401,0x24C0,0x2580,0xE541,0x2700,0xE7C1,0xE681,0x2640,0x2200,0xE2C1,0xE381,0x2340,0xE101,0x21C0,0x2080,0xE041,0xA001,0x60C0,0x6180,0xA141,0x6300,0xA3C1,0xA281,0x6240,0x6600,0xA6C1,0xA781,0x6740,0xA501,0x65C0,0x6480,0xA441,0x6C00,0xACC1,0xAD81,0x6D40,0xAF01,0x6FC0,0x6E80,0xAE41,0xAA01,0x6AC0,0x6B80,0xAB41,0x6900,0xA9C1,0xA881,0x6840,0x7800,0xB8C1,0xB981,0x7940,0xBB01,0x7BC0,0x7A80,0xBA41,0xBE01,0x7EC0,0x7F80,0xBF41,0x7D00,0xBDC1,0xBC81,0x7C40,0xB401,0x74C0,0x7580,0xB541,0x7700,0xB7C1,0xB681,0x7640,0x7200,0xB2C1,0xB381,0x7340,0xB101,0x71C0,0x7080,0xB041,0x5000,0x90C1,0x9181,0x5140,0x9301,0x53C0,0x5280,0x9241,0x9601,0x56C0,0x5780,0x9741,0x5500,0x95C1,0x9481,0x5440,0x9C01,0x5CC0,0x5D80,0x9D41,0x5F00,0x9FC1,0x9E81,0x5E40,0x5A00,0x9AC1,0x9B81,0x5B40,0x9901,0x59C0,0x5880,0x9841,0x8801,0x48C0,0x4980,0x8941,0x4B00,0x8BC1,0x8A81,0x4A40,0x4E00,0x8EC1,0x8F81,0x4F40,0x8D01,0x4DC0,0x4C80,0x8C41,0x4400,0x84C1,0x8581,0x4540,0x8701,0x47C0,0x4680,0x8641,0x8201,0x42C0,0x4380,0x8341,0x4100,0x81C1,0x8081,0x4040]

        crc_hi=0xFF
        crc_lo=0xFF

        for w in data:
                index=crc_lo ^ ord(w)
                crc_val=crc_table[index]
                crc_temp=crc_val/256
                crc_val_low=crc_val-(crc_temp*256)
                crc_lo=crc_val_low ^ crc_hi
                crc_hi=crc_temp

        crc=crc_hi*256 +crc_lo
        return crc

def hex2dec(hi_byte,lo_byte):
        val=(ord(hi_byte)*256)+ord(lo_byte)
        return val

def eac(hi_word,lo_word):
        val=(hi_word*1000)+(lo_word*0.1)
        return val
```

I tried to make the operand ^ to ** as I saw on some reference but it's not making sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `crc_temp=crc_val/256` turns `crc_temp` into a `float`. From there onward, other variables derived from it turn into `float` as well, including `crc_lo`. This ends up being a problem on the bitwise XOR operation `index = crc_lo ^ ord(w)`

A fix would be to cast the result to an `int` (since you know the value will be an `int` anyway) i.e. `crc_temp=int(crc_val/256)`. A better solution would be to use integer division, i.e. `crc_temp=crc_val//256`.

You did not provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, but I expect this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
crc_temp=crc_val/256
```

The operator `/` in Python 2 means integer division, but in Python 3 it means floating-point division. The equivalent integer-division operator in Python 3 is `//`.

```
crc_temp=crc_val//256
```